# Database setup for multiyear event manager

Tags: postgresql

I am currently in the process of setting up a database structure to manage events.

Events have properties which are stored in separate tables like 'location', 'timeslots', 'files' etc.

This in itself is not so difficult to set up. However, the tool needs to be able to host multiple events at the same time. So, for example a user can manage a the ABC event which occurs simultaneously with the DEF event. Obviously the database needs to be able to differentiate between these different events.

My first idea would be to add a table with unique identifiers describing the event (name:ABC) and then add a field to all my tables with this unique identifier.

This would however mean that the tool can become a bit slow because it has to query tables that contain data completely irrelevant to that particular event.

Are there any other solutions or should I just not worry about the bloat?

Answer (score 1):

Answering a pretty old question, but it comes out 6th in a google query for postgre database events so it could be helpful to others: no, don't worry about it. Just create indices on the foreign key in the referencing tables to speed up the look up.